# Why does 'sed q' work differently when reading from a pipe?

Tags: sed, pipe

I created a test file named 'test' that contains the following:

```
xxx
yyy
zzz
```

I ran the command:

```
(sed '/y/ q'; echo aaa; cat) < test
```

and I got:

```
xxx
yyy
aaa
zzz
```

Then I ran:

```
cat test | (sed '/y/ q'; echo aaa; cat)
```

and got:

```
xxx
yyy
aaa
```

**Question**

`sed` reads and prints until it encounters a line with 'y', then stops. In the first case, but not the second, cat reads and prints the rest.

Can someone explain what phenomenon is behind this difference in behavior?

I also noticed it works this way in Ubuntu 16.04 and Centos 6 but in Centos 7 neither command prints 'zzz'.

Comment: My guess is that `cat` (in the sub shell) can re-use the file descriptor in the first case, because stdin is bound to a real file. In the second case, stdin is from a pipe and not a real file. Note that also `(sed '/y/ q'; echo aaa; cat) < <(cat test)` does not print `zzz`.

Comment: A simpler example: `(head -n1; head -n1) < test` and `cat test | (head -n1; head -n1)`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When input file is *seekable* (like reading from regular file) or *un-seekable* (like reading from a pipe), `sed` (and other standard utilities) will behave differently (Read `INPUT FILES` section in [this link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html)).

Quote from the doc:

> When a standard utility reads a seekable input file and terminates
>   without an error before it reaches end-of-file, the utility shall
>   ensure that the file offset in the open file description is properly
>   positioned just past the last byte processed by the utility.

So in:

```
(sed '/y/ q'; echo aaa; cat) < test
```

`sed` performed `q`uit command before reaching EOF, so it left file offset at beginning of `zzz` line, so `cat` can continue printing the remain lines (GNU sed is not POSIX compliant in some condition, see below).

And continuing from the doc:

> For files
>   that are not seekable, the state of the file offset in the open file
>   description for that file is unspecified

In this case, the behavior is unspecified. Most standard tools, include `sed` will consume the input as much as possible . It read pass the `yyy` line, and `q`uit without restoring the file offset, so nothing is left for `cat`.

---

GNU `sed` is not compliant to the standard, depends on system's stdio implementation and glibc version:

```
$ (gsed '/y/ q'; echo aaa; cat) < test
xxx
yyy
aaa
```

Here, the result was got from Mac OSX 10.11.6, virtual machines Centos 7.2 - glibc 2.17, Ubuntu 14.04 - glibc 2.19, which are run on Openstack with CEPH backend.

On those systems, you can use `-u` option to achieve the standard behavior:

```
(gsed -u '/y/ q'; echo aaa; cat) </tmp/test
```

and for pipe:

```
$ cat test | (gsed -u '/y/ q'; echo aaa; cat)
xxx
yyy
aaa
zzz
```

which leads to terribly inefficient performance, because `sed` has to read one byte at a time. A partial output from `strace`:

```
$ strace -fe read sh -c '{ sed -u "/y/q"; echo aaa; cat; } <test'
...
[pid  5248] read(3, "", 4096)           = 0
[pid  5248] read(0, "x", 1)             = 1
[pid  5248] read(0, "x", 1)             = 1
[pid  5248] read(0, "x", 1)             = 1
[pid  5248] read(0, "\n", 1)            = 1
xxx
[pid  5248] read(0, "y", 1)             = 1
[pid  5248] read(0, "y", 1)             = 1
[pid  5248] read(0, "y", 1)             = 1
[pid  5248] read(0, "\n", 1)            = 1
yyy
...
```

Comment: For GNU `sed`, that depends on the system's stdio implementation. On GNU systems (with the GNU libc), GNU `sed` will be compliant as `exit()` will lseek back for files managed by stdio.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: How to verify it? With my Centos 7.2, Ubuntu 14.04  VM, `sed` isn't compliant, my manjaro laptop does, all have the same `sed`  version 4.2.2

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Sounds like something happened under the hood. On my virtual machines, `strace -f sh -c '{ sed "/y/q"; echo aaa; cat; } <test'` show that no `lseek()` was performed, while in my manjaro a `lseek()` was called before `exit_group()`.

Comment: I suppose that's down to the version of the GNU libc. You can test with a `main() { char buf[999]; gets(buf); }'` program.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Confirmed. Both my VMs have 2.17 and 2.19, while the one in my manjaro is 2.23. Is this consider a glibc bug? Do you have any information about the change between glibc versions